# First Node function to res.send if other functions success

Tags: node.js, express, http-post, httprequest

**Introduction**

I have 3 Node functions, the first retrieves data sent from front-end, the second gets a valid API key and third function posts to a API using data from the first 2 functions.

I would like to have a case statement on the first function that I can use `res.send('')`  on each case. Each case would be a indication that a function fails or passes.

**what I need**

Is a way in the second and third function function to trigger a case depending on outcome of function.

Maybe if else, if first function fails, if second fails and if third, but how to do this all from the first function ?

**For example**

```
switch(expression) {
    case 1:
        res.send('function 1 pass')
        break;
    case 2:
        res.send('function 1 fail')
        break;
    case 3:
        res.send('function 2 pass')
        break;
    case 4:
        res.send('function 2 fail')
        break;
    case 5:
        res.send('function 3 pass')
        break;
    case 6:
        res.send('function 3 fail')
        break;
    default:
        res.send('something went wrong')
}
```

**My code**

```
 var firstFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                app.post('/back-end/controller', function (req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body);
                    var login = req.body.LoginEmail;

                    if (login.length !== 0) { // maybe use node email validation ?
                        console.log("First done");
                        res.send(200,'Success',{ user: login });
                        resolve({
                            data_login_email: login
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Failed");
                        res.send(404,'Failed user not registered',{ user: login });
                    }
                });

            }, 2000);
        });
    };

    var secondFunction = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                    userKey: userkey,
                    email: emailAdmin,
                    password: password,
                    DEBUG: false
                }, function (err, client) {
                    if (err) {
                        // Authentication failed
                        console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                    } else {
                        // Authentication successful
                        var api_key = client.apiKey;
                        console.log("Authentication successful", api_key);
                        resolve({data_api: api_key});
                    }
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
    };


    function thirdFunction(result) {
        return new Promise(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var headers = {
                        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    };
                    var api = result[1].data_api;
                    var login_email = result[0].data_login_email;
                    var options = {
                        url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: headers,
                        form: {
                            'email': login_email,
                            'user_key': userkey,
                            'api_key': api
                        },
                        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                    };

// Start the request
                    rp(options)
                        .then(function (parsedBody) {
                            console.info(login_email, "Is a user, login pass!");
                            console.error("Third done");
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            console.error("fail no such user");
                            // res.status(400).send()

                        });
                }, 3000);
            }
        );
    }


Promise.all([firstFunction(),secondFunction()]).then(thirdFunction);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `switch` statement, Promises have some logic capabilities built in using `then/catch`.  If I'm understanding the problem, you could do something like this:

```
firstPromise = firstFunction()
    .then(args => {
        res.send('function 1 pass');
        return args;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('function 1 fail');
        throw err;
    });
secondPromise = secondFunction()
    .then(args => {
        res.send('function 2 pass');
        return args;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('function 2 fail');
        throw err;
    });
thirdPromise = Promise
    .all([firstPromise, secondPromise])
    .then(thirdFunction)
    .then(args => {
        res.send('function 3 pass');
        return args;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (/* `err` from thirdFunction, not firstFunction or secondFunction */)
            res.send('function 3 fail');
        throw err;
    });
```

Then you would just need to figure out the logic for checking where the error came from. One option would be tacking on a `fromThird` (or whatever name) property to the error if `thirdFunction` fails, so your condition would be `if (err.fromThird) res.send('function 3 fail');`

Comment: Thanks for this ill try and get this working and accept the answer